# Solve equation with modulo operator

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I have the equotation
$$(x-g)\mod(2g)=0,\; x \in \Bbb N, n \in \Bbb N$$
I need a formula to calculate $g$ out of a given $x$, I tried WolframAlpha, but I only get [pairs of numbers matching this equotation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%5B(x-n)%20mod%20(2n)%3D%3D0,%20n%3E0,%20x%3E0,%20n%5D).
I heard of the inverse modulo operator, but I'm not sure if or how this operate could help me here.
Since I'm not a mathematician you can hopefully forgive me, if this is a stupid question.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Some Testcases:
for $x=[1,3,5,7,9,11],\; g=1$,
for $x=[2,6,10,14,18,22],\; g=2$,
for $x=[4,12,20,28,36,44],\; g=3$,
for $x=[8,24,40,56,72,88],\; g=4$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want that $x-g=2gn$, where $n$ is some integer, which means
$$
g=\frac{x}{2n+1}
$$
So, take any odd divisor of $x$ and you'll find a value for $g$, two if you allow negative values for $g$.

For instance, if $x=1$, you only have the solutions $g=1$ or $g=-1$. For $x=3$ you can take $g=3/1=3$ or $g=3/3=1$ (or their negatives). For $x=6$, the possible values are $g=6/1=6$ or $g=6/3=2$ (plus $-6$ or $-2$).

If $x=2^k$, with $k>0$, only $g=1$ is possible.

The solution $g=4$ for $x=8$ is not good: inded $8-4\not\equiv0\pmod{2\cdot4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Well
$$x-g\equiv0 \pmod {2g} \iff x-g=(2g)k$$
for some integer $k$.

Then
 $$g=\dfrac{x}{2k+1}$$
will work whenever it's an integer. That happens for each odd factor of $x$.

I don't think there's a formula.

For every $x$ you can take $g=x$ - that corresponds to the odd factor $1$ of $x$.

For $x=1$ the only solution is $g=x=1$.

A more typical example: for $x=6$ you can have $g=6/1 = 6$ and $g=6/3 = 2$.

Comment: Where is $k$ coming from?

Comment: @RoiEX k is the factor.

Comment: @RoiEX When we have things like a|b this is the same as b=am where m is an integer. Here we have 2g|(x-g)

Comment: Your formula is working sometimes, but not always... Using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%5Bg%3D%3Dx%2F(2k%2B1),+k+mod+2+%3D%3D+1,+x%3D5,+g%5D) I get multiple and negative results... Maybe your formula is wrong, maybe I understood it wrong (please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference))